# How to close a generator in Chrome (with ES6 enabled)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, generator

In Chrome (with ES6 enabled), we can create a generator. However, it looks there is no "close" method for a generator object. How to close a generator?

If we don't close it, it is a kind of resource leak, right?

Comment: You could simply let it get garbage collected, couldn't you?

Comment: Hmm. It could be. It looks I should worry about the internal details of generator. Thank you.

Comment: This is a great question! I'm surprised that for *eight years* no one saw the value of exhaustively going over when it might actually be good to close a generator, and how you would do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can close a generator manually by calling its [`return` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator/return).

You only need to do this in the cases where the generator is not closed for you - garbage collection **won't** close it for you, but a `for...of` loop on a generator will always close it, and fully consuming a generator until it runs to the end of its code will close it.

If you're writing a generator that needs cleanup other than automatic garbage collection, you'll also need to put a `try`-`finally` inside the generator, and **do the cleanup in the `finally`** - otherwise closing the generator might not actually run your cleanup.

For example, let's say you have this **badly written** generator (I am using an interval to represent any persistent resource or external state which needs to be properly cleaned up or finalized - examples include network protocols which benefit from graceful shutdown messages, database transactions that need committing, and so on):

```js
function* generator_with_bad_cleanup(identity)
{
    let interval = setInterval(
        console.log,
        1000,
        "generator", identity, "still not fully cleaned up",
    )
    yield 1
    yield 2
    yield 3
    yield 4
    clearInterval(interval)
}
```

If you just run this in the console, the generator itself gets "closed" and garbage collected, but you'll see the interval keep printing to the console, forever:

```js
for(let x of generator_with_bad_cleanup(1))
{
    console.log("consumed:", x)
    if(x == 3)  // exit early for some reason
    {
        break
    }
}
```

Here's the **correctly written** fixed version:

```js
function* generator_with_good_cleanup(identity)
{
    let interval
    try
    {
        interval = setInterval(
            console.log,
            1000,
            "generator", identity, "still not fully cleaned up",
        )
        yield 1
        yield 2
        yield 3
        yield 4
    }
    finally
    {
        clearInterval(interval)
    }
}
```

Now if you do the same thing, everything gets cleaned up - the generator, and the interval:

```js
for(let x of generator_with_good_cleanup(2))
{
    console.log("consumed:", x)
    if(x == 3)
    {
        break
    }
}
```

As you can see based on that last example, `for(... of generator_instance)` loops automatically close generators even if you leave them early, causing any `finally` clauses in the generator to run even if it didn't finish. So if you're looping on it, or doing something else which automatically closes it, you don't have to do anything special from outside the generator.

But for example, if you are manually stepping through a generator by using the iterator protocol and you don't finish consuming the generator, the cleanup won't run, and you'll see the interval keep printing to the console forever again:

```js
generator_instance = generator_with_good_cleanup(3)
generator_instance.next()  // {value: 1, done: false}
generator_instance.next()  // {value: 2, done: false}
generator_instance.next()  // {value: 3, done: false}
```

**Even if `generator_instance` gets garbage-collected** it will **not** be **closed**, so the interval will keep running:

```js
// override the only reference to the generator instance:
generator_instance = null
// interval still alive
```

So in those cases, you need to manually call the generator's `return` method:

```js
generator_instance = generator_with_good_cleanup(4)
generator_instance.next()  // {value: 1, done: false}
generator_instance.next()  // {value: 2, done: false}
generator_instance.next()  // {value: 3, done: false}
// interval still running here
generator_instance.return()
// interval now cleared
```

Note that you don't need to call `return` if you consume the generator until it runs to completion:

```js
generator_instance = generator_with_good_cleanup(5)
generator_instance.next()  // {value: 1, done: false}
generator_instance.next()  // {value: 2, done: false}
generator_instance.next()  // {value: 3, done: false}
generator_instance.next()  // {value: 4, done: false}
// interval still running here
generator_instance.next()  // {value: undefined, done: true}
// interval now cleared
```

(If you have to be compatible with older browsers that didn't yet have `return`, you can [`throw`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator/throw) an exception into the generator. This will work just as well, but the only pitfall is that a badly written generator could have a clumsy `try`-`catch` that swallows the error you threw into it before ever getting to the `finally`.)

Answer (score -1):

An iterator don't need to be closed because it gets automatically garbage collected if its no more used.

It's similar to an array or any other object : You don't need to "close" or delete an object in Javascript - the Garbage Collector will take care of cleaning it up.

Comment: The biggest problem with "you don't need to close because garbage collection" is that it limits what kind of robust cleanup generators can be written to do. For example, you can wrap your entire generator body in a `try`-`finally` and put some clean up in the `finally`, but garbage collection won't run it for you if the generator was fully consumed. (Compare Python, where generators have a `close` method, which will throw a `GeneratorExit` from the spot of the last `yield` that the generator reached.)

Comment: Sorry, typo: I meant to say "but garbage collection won't run it for you if the generator was***n't*** fully consumed".  Anyway, JavaScript generators actually have a `return` method which does in fact manually close the generator. However JavaScript does not automatically close generators when they are garbage collected (Python does not guarantee this, but as an implementation detail, it is normal for Python implementations to close generators when they are garbage collected). JavaScript *does* automatically close them when `for...of` loops on them exit, but if you bypass that, GC won't help.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't downvote this earlier because I don't like to downvote answers just because the answer seems incomplete or misleading to me, and maybe I'm now emotionally tilted because what brought be back here was getting a -1 without comment on my answer, but right now it seems to me that if people believe that garbage collection is sufficient for all generator cleanup, that will have the negative effect of people writing less robust code, and releasing libraries that don't even make it *possible* to write maximally robust code, so I'm changing my non-vote to a -1 on this.